# React Native Ad network wrappers

Tags: ios, react-native, wrapper, ads

Are there any ad network wrappers besides Google's Admob for React Native? Like Chartboost, Flurry or...well anything else in fact. I haven't found anything else in my searches so does that mean we can only use Admob?

Answer (score 0):

Appodeal provides a react native integration now. You can choose react native framework when registering your app on appodeal

**EDIT:**
Appodeal now discontinues the support of their react-native wrapper

[See here](https://blog.appodeal.com/blog/2017/11/21/framework-policy-changes/)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been looking around on this topic too. And here is my take so far. Probably late for the original post. But it might be helpful for people who find this via search in the future (like me).

**AdMob: Supported and verified**

I managed to make this work. In terms of dependency, AdMob needs FireBase. But FireBase does not support React Native out of box. I used React-Native-Firebase to make it work. 
https://rnfirebase.io/

https://firebase.google.com/

https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/

**FB Ads: Supported**

I haven’t verified it myself. But it seems to be well documented. (And React Native being related to Facebook, I’d be surprised if it weren’t supported.) 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbads

**Flurry: NOT supported**

Flurry Analytics supports React Native but Flurry Ads do not. Below is message from their support team when I asked them about this.

"Thank you for contacting Flurry Technical Support. We offer a React Native wrapper, however it does not currently support ads, only analytics. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/react-native/ "

**MoPub: Not really**

I’ve found two React Native wrappers. One is old and no longer updated. (The authors seem to be actively monitoring the discussions and replying to queries. But they are no longer providing tech support.) And the other is very new and doesn’t seem to have enough documentation or evidence that it actually works.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub-sdk

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know appodeal supports react native. + it provides access to facebook, avocarrot, inmobi, smaato, mopub and startapp alongside with openx and flurry for native ads.

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-react-demo ? I couldn't find anything else regarding it.